# Problem with Quasar, parse and back4app together with vite

Tags: parse-platform, vite, quasar-framework, back4app

Im using Vite and quasar together wth parse plattform via back4app. Im using it like this:

```
**src/boot:**
import { Parse } from "parse";

export default ({ app }) => {
    Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com";
    Parse.initialize(
        "MY_APP_ID",
        "MY_JS_KEY"
   );
   app.config.globalProperties.$parse = Parse;
};

**in quasar.config.js**
    boot: [
        "parse", // Add 'parse' to the boot array
    ],
```

Im using node 18.12.1
parse 4.3.1

Im getting this error as soon as I run quasar dev

> client-entry.js:106 [Quasar] boot error: TypeError: EventEmitter is
> not a constructor
> at new LiveQuery2 (ParseLiveQuery.js:57:20)
> at Object._initialize (Parse.js:156:23)
> at Object.initialize (Parse.js:148:11)
> at Array.default (parse.js:5:9)
> at start (client-entry.js:90:25)
> at client-entry.js:159:7

I have tried to change version of parse to 4.2.0 and 4.3.0 and also changed nodeversion but still doesnt work.

What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**
this solves that problem:
pnpm install events

however I now get:
RESTController.js:141 Refused to get unsafe header "access-control-expose-headers"

The initialization of Parse with the Application ID and JavaScript Key using Parse.initialize should take care of setting these headers under the hood. Can it be somewhere to define my headers?